# Triband vertical antenna 6/2/70

Tags: antenna

I wish to fit this on the house gable end, however the location has a metal phone line bracket that will be just bellow the antenna radials.

Will this cause any detrimental effects?

Comment: Probably not. Try it.

Comment: Objects that are very small compared to the wavelength [typically don't matter](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/effect-of-small-amount-of-metal-on-twin-lead).

Comment: Can you insert a photo of the bracket and the surrounding area into your question? That might help.

Answer (score 2):

For safety sake, make absolutely certain that the wire and bracket is a phone line and not a power line. Miscategorizing the line could be fatal. Also, generally an overhead phone line is in close proximity to an overhead power line. Make certain that you have ample clearance from the power line, during and after installation. Consider your reach distance, your antenna height, your ladder, etc.

The bracket, since it is below the ground plane, will probably not have any affect unless it is quite large. I would, however, be thinking about the phone line itself. There is the possibility that enough RF energy could couple to the phone line so as to create RF interference.

A simple preventative measure would be to snap on a couple of RFI suppression ferrite cores on the phone line (never the power line!). This may help to mitigate any potential RFI. Using one core of type 31 or 43 material and one core of type 61 material would cover the full frequency range of your antenna. Snap on ferrite cores are available from a wide variety of vendors such as the one from DigiKey:

[image]